# Kali Linux VirtualBox refuses to connect to Wi-Fi network

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, networkmanager

I installed Kali Linux on VirtualBox, but I can't see any available Wi-Fi networks. Sometimes it will show them for a second. I will type in the password for my Wi-Fi but it won't connect

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `nmcli networking on`

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the command doesn't return anything

Comment: Yes, that's normal. But after executing this command, you should see your networks again (in the UI network manager). nmcli is the network-manager-cli (command line interface) tool. Just a hint: Kali is not the easiest distro for beginners.